# What substances I can use to clean the touch sensitive screens like iPhone, iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, screen, macos

I heard that you are not supposed to use substances containing alcohol because it will destroy the anti-grease coating layer that's above the glass.

The problems is that just water and microfiber cloth is not always enough and I want to know what is safe to use.

Update: Please do not recommend a specific product, or at least do not recommend it wihout specifing the content. This is important because most products are not usually available outside the US.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found that the best substance is no substance. If you can grab some microfiber lens cloths online, you won't be disappointed. They absorb the finger oils well. I usually just breathe on my screen a little bit, then use circular swipes with a microfiber cloth.

If you are careful, any glass cleaner is fine. The reason this isn't recommended is due to the large percent of the market that would just blindly spray cleaner all over their device (causing a short), and the other percent of the market with non-glass screens. If you spray the cloth you are using, then wipe, it'll be fine.

---

Update 3/21:
My favorite method now is using Zeiss Pre-Moistened Lens Cloths Wipes. They're at Amazon and Sam's Club. I keep a box in the office and box at home.

Answer (score 3):

I've used iKlear on my iPhone and mac LCD's without any issues.

http://www.klearscreen.com/Default.aspx

Comment: This is sold at the Apple retail stores. It's cheap, works great and comes with a microfibre cloth. It's designed for safe use on electronic devices.

Answer (score 1):

Wiping it over a clean pair of old jeans does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure alcohol is a bad idea in almost any case.

Check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6590/115) question.

Answer (score 0):

I find cotton very effective, completely clean, oil free and dust free within five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Pure alcohol is one of the only cleaners that isn't incredibly caustic, and it's actually usable on circuitry, provided it's turned off.

I would recommend a microfiber cloth such as the one that comes with the Apple iPad case, or a clean cloth sprayed lightly with any glass cleaner. It is, after all, glass. I haven't heard of it reacting with the oleophobic / lipophobic coating.