# Is there any particular cleaning solution for the MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Is there any cleaning solution for the MacBook Pro?
How should I clean my MacBook? Which fabric should I use to clean it?

Comment: Check also this post: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6590/cleaning-white-macbook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a dry microfiber cloth on my screen. I found them in a two-pack of washcloth-sized at Dollar General.

If you want a cleaning solution, the Apple Store folks, at least in Madison WI, fully endorse iKlean and use it on their display models every night. I can't vouch because I haven't used it, but I figure Apple knows Apple well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from the [MacBook Pro: Care, Use, and Safety Information](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro/care/) page.

> **Cleaning Your MacBook Pro Display**.
>   Follow these general rules when cleaning the screen.
>   Shut down your MacBook Pro, detach the power adapter, and remove the battery.
>   Dampen a clean, soft, lint-free cloth or paper with water only and wipe the screen. Do not spray liquid directly on the screen.
>
> **Cleaning Your MacBook Pro**
>   Follow these general rules when cleaning the outside of your computer and its components:
>   Shut down your MacBook Pro, detach the power adapter, and remove the battery.
>   Use a damp, soft, lint-free cloth to clean the computer’s exterior. Avoid getting moisture in any openings. Do not spray any type of liquid directly on the computer.
>   Don’t use aerosol sprays, solvents, or abrasives.

I'm sure people are not using only water to clean their MacBooks and they are fine, but for me a wet microfiber cloth is sufficient.

Comment: Hahaha. It's funny because they say to remove the battery.

Comment: @Merchako back in 2011 MacBooks with removable batteries were common.

Comment: I'm well aware. I have nothing against the answer. Their advice is ironic in retrospect.

Comment: @Merchako no offense taken:)

Answer (score 2):

I use the same cloth I get from the optical shop, microfiber cleaning cloth, and add just a drop of water to the cloth, not the screen. I turn the screen backlight completely down and shine a bright point source light (aka a desk lamp) onto the screen, with the screen turned so that you can see the screen cruft and fingerprints (and not yourself, lest you start preening).

If you keep the microfiber cloth clean they might last a geologic epoch or two.

I recommend not using anything other than a drop of water on the cloth. The microfiber cloth is a relatively new and *dynamite* technology for this job. You shouldn't need glass cleaner, and you might in fact clean off any factory-installed screen coatings. Cleaning the older silver laptop keyboards with a similar cleaner  rewards you by removing the paint.

Answer (score 0):

With my Unibody Macbook Pro I just use a soft cloth moisted with a bit of glass cleaner (nothing fancy, any multisurface cleaner that happens to be around at home)

I haven't had any issues with this in my Unibody Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a lot of the previous commenters and want to add my opinion to the mix.

As an Apple Authorized Service Provider (AASP) we clean each machine that comes in for repair/upgrade. There are some very overpriced cleaners out there and we've tried a lot of them. iKlean is good, but we regularly use this:

http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=109&cp_id=10902&cs_id=1090201&p_id=5177&seq=1&format=2

Can't beat the price! If you've never looked at Monoprice, they have some great prices on quality products. HDMI, Cat 5 - 6, etc.

*I don't work for Monoprice, but I enjoy sharing companies that I believe in and trust.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to wjl's method, I have used a microfibre polishing cloth alongside a device & screen cleaner solution from [Muc-Off](http://muc-off.com/en/16-electronics). There products are also available to buy from the retailer Amazon (where applicable).

(They also have a range of products for motoring & bicycles as well).